# Real Analysis Qual Problem

Tags: real-analysis

I feel that this is an easy problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it.  I would appreciate some help.

Suppose that $f_j$ is a sequence of functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying

$(i)$ $||f_j||_\infty \leq 1$;

$(ii)$ the $f_j$ converge pointwise to $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$

Does it follow that the $\hat{f}_j$ converge pointwise to $\hat{f}$?

Comment: What is $\hat f_j$ and $\hat f$

Comment: Looks like Fourier transform.

Comment: Yes, Fourier transform.

Comment: Generally speaking you can't, under most circumstances, expect the conclusion of the Dominated/Vitali convergence theorem to be true without their hypotheses. Here the $L^{\infty}$-boundedness condition is worthless: simply take $f_j(x) = \chi_{[j,j+1]}(x)$ and then the fourier transforms don't converge at zero. On the other hand, you could get a positive answer were the sequence $\{f_j\}$ uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $f_j = 1$ at some tiny interval around $x=j$ and vanishes at other points, then $f_j$ is bounded and approximate $0$ pointwisely.

But for integral $\hat{f_j}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_j e^{-i\xi x}dx$, at $\xi = 0$, we can see that $\hat{f_j}(0)$ is not going to be approximating $0$.